# Sharing data between deskop application and web application using azure

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I've developed a windows form application. However,I want to upload data from that application into a cloud server and then develop a web application to retrieve that data. Is it possible to accomplish that using windows azure?

If not, is there any way to accomplish that?Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Regards

Comment: Could you be more specific? What kind of data? Binary? Structured text? database? How much data? How often?
And yeah, you should be able to accomplish that.

Comment: It is just string and integers, how much data and how often i am still not sure, because so far i had gone through azure documentation and I can't really find a direct method to do that...

Comment: Depending on your requirements you can simply use table or blob storage, direct access to SQL azure or Azure table storage. All methods except SQL Azure (which is TDS) are friendly HTTPS services with available client libraries.
If you have more complex requirements you can host your own services in Azure compute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your requirements I would architect the solution as such.

**Data Storage**
SQL Azure or Blob Storage.

If you need to run advanced queries on the data I would suggest SQL Azure, but the cost per GB is more expensive. If advanced queries aren't really going to be an issue, then Blob Storage. Also if you are only going to store a small amount of data as in a few GB's at top, SQL Azure may still be the best choice if you are familar with SQL. It may have a quicker dev time.

**Web Service**
To access the data from your desktop I would recommend having a web service. Preferably a JSON compatible one, running on an Azure instance. Or you can check out: http://www.asp.net/web-api

**Desktop App**
Well that can really be anything, but if you want a pretty looking app, then WPF is the way to go. If you want speed then a WinForms app would be best, or console if it's just a plain sending data and limited UI.

**Web App**
Not sure on what this is about? But a plain old ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC will do the solution, also have this hosted on an Azure Instance. You can have the webservice and app running on the same role.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve it. You may use an SQL Azure database and expose it via [Open Data](http://odata.org) depending on the requirements. On the other hand you also may use [Azure Connect](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/virtual-network/) to make some kind of VPN between your desktop app and cloud services.

Cheers,